# Poisson differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I'm stuck on an old exam question:

Let $\Omega = \{(x,y) \in R^2 : 1 < x^2 + y^2 < a \}$.
Determine the unique solution for the following boundary condition problem:

$\Delta u = 1$  for $(x,y) \in \Omega$

$\frac{\delta u}{\delta n}(x,y) = 0$ for $x^2+y^2=a$

$u(x,y) = 0$ for $x^2 + y^2 = 1$

What I figured out:

You need to express the problem in polar coordinates:

$\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta r^2} + \frac{1}{r}\frac{\delta{u}}{\delta r} + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\delta^2 u}{\delta \phi^2} = 1$

$\frac{\delta u}{\delta r}(\phi, a) = 0$ for $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$

$u(\phi, 1) = 0$ for $\phi \in [0,2\pi)$

I searched on the internet for solutions, but only found solution methods for the second boundary condition, the first boundary condition gives me a hard time trying to adapt these. Also my book does only briefly mention poisson equations, though la place equations are explained thoroughly.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You can see that the boundary conditions do not depend on $\phi$. Then $u$ does not (because of the uniqueness of the solution of suh problems). Then soluve the ODE.

Comment: Thank you, I solved it :). $u''(r)  + (1/r) u'(r) = 0$ gives $u(r) = c_1 log (r) + c_2$, and then the particular solution becomes $u(r) = 1/4r^2$.

Comment: it should depend on $a$, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes. The final solution becomes $1/4r^2 - (a/2) log(r) - 1/4$. The $c_1$ and $c_2$ values are determined by the boundary conditions.